# Is there a way to hide some of the columns value from charts in Superset

Tags: user-interface, apache-superset

I have a requirement in which some of the columns value need to be hide from chart for the security reasons, For eg. there are 4 columns (A, B, C, D) which i have selected in groupby dropdown option and i just want to display the values of (B, C, D) only not of A, but A will be the part of query computation in Hive.

So can it be done in superset?

In any of the table there can be 2-3 columns which could have  sensitive info which we usually want to restrict unauthorised users to see it.

I am able to Hash the value of column A, but i want to hide it from display altogether.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to create two datasets (Superset's abstraction on top of tabular datasets), one of which points to a view that has only a subset of the columns (B, C, D). Users can be given access to one dataset or the other, depending on their level of access. On downside with this approach is that charts and dashboards may have to be duplicated to work for the different roles.